# Images.xcassets: error: ERROR: Each TDDistiller instance can be distilled only one time

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, xcode9.2

Couldn't find proper solution for this.
"ERROR: Each TDDistiller instance can be distilled only one time." 
while compiling the project

i've just restart my mac and then my project worked fine for some time. and after that it gives the same error. Anyone got proper solution for this? that I don't have to restart my mac several times.

Answer (score 1):

Clean DerivedData, close Simulator and restart Xcode. Not optimal solution, but better than restarting your Mac.

Answer (score -1):

Reinstall `Xcode` solve my problem , Or update it